# And statement in WHERE slows SQL query down dramatically

Tags: mysql, sql

And Statement in Where slows SQL query down drastically.

```
SELECT * FROM quant.intra5 where DATE(datetime) = '2016-05-03' and symbol = 'AAAP';
```

The above statement will always cause sql to time out. Giving error code 2013

But if I use single condition like

```
SELECT * FROM quant.intra5 where DATE(datetime) = '2016-05-03'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM quant.intra5 where  symbol = 'AAAP';
```

The query returns almost instantly.

The table is 4gb large with an auto_increment id.

## UPDATE ON 27TH.OCT

The following code will run smothly

```
SELECT i.*
FROM quant.intra5 i 
WHERE datetime >= DATE('2016-05-03') AND
      symbol = "AAAP"
```

But not this one,This one times out everytime.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM quant.intra5 i 
WHERE datetime >= DATE('2016-05-03') AND
      datetime < DATE('2016-05-04') AND
      symbol = "AAAP"
```

## Interesting stuff follows

This one can fetch

```
SELECT *
FROM quant.intra5
WHERE symbol='AAAP' AND
      datetime > DATE('2016-05-04')
```

But not this one

```
SELECT *
FROM quant.intra5
WHERE symbol='AAAP' AND
      datetime < DATE('2016-05-04')
```

Comment: Please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE quant.intra5;` and `EXPLAIN <your query>` for all three queries.

Comment: 'intra5', 'CREATE TABLE `intra5` (\n  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `symbol` text,\n  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,\n  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,\n  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,\n  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,\n  `volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55834116 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Comment: I guess it can have something to do with this, because I tryed same query with another table it worked just find.

Comment: basically what this query do is to find all the rows with symbol = 'AAAP' and date = '2016-05-03'

Answer (score 1):

To really understand the performance, you need to look at the explain plans.

For best performance, I would suggest writing your query as:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM quant.intra5 i 
WHERE datetime >= DATE('2016-05-03') AND
      datetime < DATE('2016-05-04') AND
      symbol = 'AAAP';
```

For this, you want an index on `quant.intra5(symbol, datetime)`.  Note that the order of the columns matters.

As for performance, you may be confusing returning the *first* row with completing the *entire* query.  Without your additional restriction, MySQL may find some matching rows.  But it sounds like it needs to scan the entire table.

Of course, it is possible that you have individual indexes on each of the columns, which facilitate the simpler `WHERE` clauses.  The data for your particular query may be so sparse that that index does not particularly help for the more specific query.  In any case, the index you want is above.

Comment: Hello Gordon Linoff, I understand what you are sying, but after changing with your code,it still times out.

Comment: @TomTian . . . Do you have the two-part index mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes I did, strange issue here.